# Bluetooth can't be enabled after hibernation(using terminal to hibernate) Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, bluetooth, hibernate

Bluetooth can't be enabled.
It was working perfectly until I "hibernate" the laptop using the terminal. I was on Ubuntu 15.04 and my laptop is an Acer Aspire V 17 Nitro:
Core i7
Nvidia GTX 860M.
RAM 6Gb
I've ended the upgrade to 15.10 this morning hoping that the problem would be solved but the Bluetooth can't still be enabled.
Any advices??
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing firmware for the bluetooth to function

```
cd /lib/firmware/ar3k
sudo wget http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/ar3k/AthrBT_0x11020100.dfu
sudo wget http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/ar3k/ramps_0x11020100_40.dfu
```

Reboot

This firmware is also in the linux-firmware package for xenial

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.
I've done as you said and it works perfectly.
Thanks for your help.
I put it on solved.

Comment: I read your [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1520750) and the attached files showed what was wrong

Comment: Oh ok I see. Its very nice anyway